# Passing option value to AWS CLI command from variable or file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am writing a script which creates various CloudFormation stacks, and want to start next stack when previous is done. Instead of 'sleep WHATEVER' I wish to use  ['stack-exists' subcommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-exists.html). ID of the stack in question is in StackId variable, and also is in StackId plaintext file.
Here's the thing:

```
$ echo ${StackId}
"arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:461950495720:stack/CF-VPC-NEW/8031d670-aa78-11ec-986e-02784df577a8"
$ aws cloudformation wait stack-exists  --stack-name ${StackId}

Waiter StackExists failed: Max attempts exceeded. Previously accepted state: Matched expected service error code: ValidationError
$ cat StackId
"arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:461950495720:stack/CF-VPC-NEW/8031d670-aa78-11ec-986e-02784df577a8"
$ aws cloudformation wait stack-exists  --stack-name `cat StackId`

Waiter StackExists failed: Max attempts exceeded. Previously accepted state: Matched expected service error code: ValidationError
$ aws cloudformation wait stack-exists  --stack-name "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:461950495720:stack/CF-VPC-NEW/8031d670-aa78-11ec-986e-02784df577a8"
$ echo $?
0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `StackId` contains **quotation marks**. So it was created as :

```
StackId=\"arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:461950495720:stack/CF-VPC-NEW/8031d670-aa78-11ec-986e-02784df577a8\"
```

rather then

```
StackId="arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:461950495720:stack/CF-VPC-NEW/8031d670-aa78-11ec-986e-02784df577a8"
```

Comment: It was created parsing create-stack output, and I left quotation marks intact intentionally. It was a mistake, thanks.

Comment: BTW, using 'aws cloudformation deploy' instead of 'aws cloudformation create-stack' waits for completion out of the box (but returns a stack name instead if arn).